# What is wrong with my translation?

Tags: na-adjectives

Take the following sentence.
人は魚が好きだ.
I thought this meant "Person is likable fish" (I'm new at this)
I was told it meant "People like fish"
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AはBが好き/嫌いだ means A likes/dislikes B.

は indicates the theme and が indicate the subject, it litteraly means "About A : B is liked".

There are many adjectives that follow this pattern in which what would be the direct object in english is the subject in japanese.

> 私は彼が羨ましい。
>
> I envy him. "To me, he is enviable."

Not strictly an answer to your question but the AはBが + adjective structure is also used in many cases where the verb "to have" would be used in english.

> あの女の子は背が高い。
>
> That girl is tall. "That girl has a tall height (back)", "About that girl, her height is tall."
>
> 犬は鼻が長い。
>
> Dogs have long noses.

Comment: Thanks. Can now differentiate between wa and ga as well.